# Separate checkbox for each table row in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a functional component which returns a table with many rows like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

function Table({ data }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
    };

return (
    // Some table head code
    <TableBody>
        {data.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell align="left">
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={checked}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                    />
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            // More table row code here
        ))}
    </TableBody>
  );
}
```

Each row has a checkbox. The problem is when I click on a checkbox, all other checkboxes on the other rows are checked. How should I go about this.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add "Check All" features?

Comment: No, I just want the checkbox I checked is checked, not all.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I tried this and it works:

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

function Table({ data }) {
const [checked, setChecked] = useState({});
const handleChange = (event, row) => {
    setChecked({ id: row.id, check: event.target.checked });
};

return (
    // Some table head code
    <TableBody>
        {data.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell align="left">
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={checked}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, row)}
                        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                    />
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        ))}
    </TableBody>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, **the reason why it's happening is that you're passing the same state and change handler function to each input**. If we were to take away the layer of reference of functions and state values here's what you currently have in code

```js
.map => new Map([
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={false}
  onChange={(event) => set(event.target.checked)}
 />,
 <input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={false}
  onChange={(event) => set(event.target.checked)}
 />
 // ... and so on for each and every one of them
])
```

**So if you check one, it changes all of them**

You need to declare an individual state for each checkbox, or union them into a single large reduced state of checkboxes. Easiest way to do this without having to manually declare each and every checkbox is to generate them dynamically and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them to a single state:

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react'

// example of what gets passed
const data = [
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
]

// Checkbox component
const Table ({ data }) => {
  // in case 'data' is async you'll need to use useEffect or useCallback
  // generates individual state for each data row
  const initialState = data.reduce(
    (state, current) => (
      Object.assign(state, { [current.id]: false })
    ),
    {}
  ) //  {0: false, 1: false, 2: false, 3: false}

  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState(initialState)
}
```

Now that we have our state taken care of, we just need to write our `onChange` handler.

```
const handleToggle = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { checked, name } = event.target
  setCheckboxes(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name]: checked,
  }))
}
```

and produce your return:

```js
return (
  <div className="App">
    {/* in case your id does not match index, use Object.entries instead */}
    {Object.values(checkboxes).map((isChecked, index) => (
      <TableRow key={index}>
        <TableCell align="left>
          <Checkbox
            name={index}
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={handleToggle}
          />
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Here's a working codesandbox example:

[image: Edit cocky-gauss-s5eh8]